# Solaris: how to forward cron e-mails?

Tags: solaris, cron, email

If a **cron** job produces output it is e-mailed to the user's account.

I would like to redirect this e-mail to another e-mail account. Preferably on a user-by-user basis.

I've looked into some options that are often mentioned in other postings:

1. Using the cron `MAILTO` variable. Won't work. That one is not
   supported on Solaris. It is a Linux thing, potentially also a BSD
   thing, but certainly doesn't exist on Solaris.
2. Using the `~/.forward` file. Can't make that work. I suspect it is
   because this file is really related to `sendmail` universe and I'm
   not sure Solaris cron actually uses `sendmail` to send its e-mails.

To get to the bottom of this I guess I need to understand exactly by which mechanism Solaris cron sends e-mails.

Anyone ?

Comment: Solaris does use sendmail and does honor `~/.forward`. The global aliases file is `/etc/mail/aliases`.

Comment: You might find http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119763/solaris-cron-ignoring-mail-aliases useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to forward all of a user's mail, not just the mail from Cron, Solaris does support [`~/.forward`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5174/6mbb98ue9/index.html). Solaris also supports global aliases in `/etc/mail/aliases`; if you modify this file, you need to run [`newaliases`](http://docs.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/newaliases-1m/index.html).

If you only want to forward mail from cron, you can set a filter in `~/.forward` or `/etc/mail/aliases`. I don't think Solaris comes with any useful filtering tool preinstalled; the classic program for this is [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/). Use `|/usr/local/bin/procmail` as your filter, and something like this as your `~/.procmailrc` (untested):

```
:0
* ^From: Cron Daemon <unixhacker2010@yourhostname.example.com>
* ^Subject: Cron .*
! otheraddress@otherhost.example.com
```

Alternatively, you can mail the output of the job explicitly from the crontab. Install [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) (I don't know how easy it is to compile under Solaris), which contains a command `ifne` that executes a program only if its standard input is not empty.

```
… 2>&1 | ifne mailx -s 'Cron output' otheraddress@otherhost.example.com
```

Comment: I've accepted this one as an answer. I believe my problems were completely related to having screwed up configuration for sendmail.

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember that Solaris was that different.

Is there not the `/etc/aliases` file (might be a different location on Solaris?) where you can simply put a pair from - to?

After that `newaliases` should activate the change.

Comment: Thanks. Can't make that work. I got a suspicion that my underlying problem is that I've somehow messed up my sendmail setup on this particular host. (yes, I'm back to believing that sendmail is involved ... after all).

Answer (score 1):

The code posted in [Solaris cron ignoring mail aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119763/solaris-cron-ignoring-mail-aliases) could help clarify those for whom this still does not work.