# Solaris cron ignoring mail aliases?

Tags: cron, solaris, email

As a Solaris user, I want cron jobs generated emails for the `localuser@server` to be forwarded to my `myuser@sample.com` email account, so that I read only one inbox.

To resolve this I have forwarded `localuser` to `myuser@sample.com` and according to the aliases test it does work as expected:

```
 $ sudo sendmail -v -bv localuser
 Password: 
 localuser... aliased to myuser@sample.com
```

The `mconnect` command also confirms the alias is set.

However any communication from cron seems to not use aliases:

> `Mar 14 17:54:27 localuser sendmail[9249]: [ID 801593 mail.info]
>   s2ELsRC2009249: from=localuser, size=13, class=0, nrcpts=1,
>   msgid=<201403142154.s2ELsRC2009249@myserver.sample.com>,
>   relay=localuser@localhost`
>
> `Mar 14 17:54:28 localuser sendmail[9249]: [ID 801593 mail.info]
>   s2ELsRC2009249: to=localuser, ctladdr=localuser (100/1),
>   delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30013,
>   relay=smtp.sample.com. [192.168.0.2], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (
>   <201403142154.s2ELsRC2009249@myserver.sample.com> Queued mail for
>   delivery)`

This results in errors of course in `smtp.sample.com` as user `localuser` does not exist there.

Any ideas how can I debug what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

As posted in http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2014/06/devops-need-no-words-but-code-how-to.html here is the answer. I know ot is not recommended to edit *cf files directly so you know the drill. Hopefully it will help somebody out there.

```
smarthost=mail.sample.com
user=me
alertlist=alert@mail.sample.com
/opt/csw/bin/gsed -i "s/^DS[\s]*.*/DS $smarthost/g" /etc/mail/submit.cf
/opt/csw/bin/gsed -i "s/^DS[\s]*.*/DS $smarthost/g" /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
/opt/csw/bin/gsed -i "/$user:/d" /etc/aliases
echo "$user:$alertlist" >> /etc/aliases
/opt/csw/bin/gsed -i "/root:/d" /etc/aliases
echo "root:$alertlist" >> /etc/aliases
svcadm restart sendmail
echo "So that we never miss again an important communication from servers" | mailx  -s "`hostname` As a sysadmin I want to receive my user mail notifications in my personal email address" me
echo "So that we never miss again an important communication from servers" | mailx  -s "`hostname` As a sysadmin I want to receive root mail notifications in my personal email address" root
```